# Using the score from first lightgbm as init score to second lightgbm gives different results

Tags: python, machine-learning, lightgbm

I tried to test the init score function in lightgbm. First I ran lightgbm once to get a prediction. Then I used the score from first lightgbm model as the init score to the second lightgbm model (exactly the same as the first model except for init score). I just wonder why the second model has different results.

I tried to modify the hyperparameters of lightgbm. For example, double the n_estimators. However, I could not produce the same results as the second model with init score. Which hyperparameters should I change to get the same results?

```py
model = LGBMRegressor(max_depth=3, n_estimators=200, silent=True,
                      num_leaves=6, subsample=0.8, colsample_bytree=1,
                      n_jobs=2, objective='regression', learning_rate=0.01,
                      random_state=0)

model.fit(X_train, y_train)
yhat = model.predict(X_train)
y_score = model.predict(X_train, raw_score=True)

model2 = model
model2.fit(X_train, y_train, init_score=y_score)
yhat2 = model2.predict(X_train)
```

Comment: why do you want to get the same result ? what's the point

Comment: I'm trying to understand why I got different results. I think in this case adding the init score is just like double the iterations of the boosting tree. However, changing n_estimators did not work well.

Answer (score 1):

The init_score should be added to the predictions. i.e. prediction = yhat2 + y_score